# OpenCL CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE when launching Kernel at Both NVIDIA and Intel GPUs

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl

This might not the the most narrowed down problem but..

The program implements a wrapper around all of the OpenCL stuff. The wrapper detects all of the OpenCL devices then wraps these into yet another wrappers. The device wrappers contain all the objects related to it such as allocated cl_mem buffers the  associated context etc.

I have chacked multiple times if there are no mistake, if no pointers are reused like if due to some error device wrappers from different platforms would share the same platform pointer. but no.

The problem:
When I divide work between all the computational devices on my laptop (CPU+Intel GPU + Nvidia GPU), kernel execution issued to the NVIDIA GPU crahses with CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE.

I've checked everything.

I've tried the following scenarios:

- Intel GPU and CPU simultaneously => everything works fine
- two CPUs simultaneously (server) => everything works fine
- if I mix devices from two platforms on the laptop => it crashes with CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE. it crashes ONLY on the Nvidia GPU.

most of the initialization code is below.

```
std::cout << "Initializing the OpenCL engine..\n";
cl_int ret;
unsigned int nrOfActiveContexts = 0;
ret = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &mRetNumPlatforms);
if (mRetNumPlatforms > 0)
{

    this->mPlatforms.resize(mRetNumPlatforms);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "No OpenCL platform available.\n");
    exit(1);
}

ret = clGetPlatformIDs(mRetNumPlatforms, mPlatforms.data(), NULL);

std::vector<cl_device_id> devices;
cl_context context;
cl_uint numberOfDevices;
//query for available compute platforms
for (int i = 0; i < mPlatforms.size() ; i++)
{
    bool error = false;
    numberOfDevices = 0;
    devices.clear();
    context = NULL;
    cl_device_type deviceTypes = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL;
    if (useCPU &&useGPU)
        deviceTypes = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL;
    else if (useCPU)
        deviceTypes = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU;
    else if (useGPU)
        deviceTypes = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(mPlatforms[i], deviceTypes, 0, NULL, &numberOfDevices);
    if (numberOfDevices > 0)
    {
        devices.resize( numberOfDevices);
        ret = clGetDeviceIDs(mPlatforms[i], deviceTypes,
            numberOfDevices, devices.data(), NULL);
    }
    else continue;

    context = clCreateContext(NULL, numberOfDevices, devices.data(), NULL, NULL, &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        throw(std::abort);
    mContexts.push_back(context);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        error = true;
    }
    //query device properties create Workers
    size_t ret_size;
    cl_uint compute_units;
    cl_ulong max_alloc;
    size_t max_work_size;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<char> c_name;
    for (int y = 0; y < devices.size(); y++)
    {
        ret_size = compute_units = max_alloc = max_work_size = 0;
        c_name.clear();

        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_NAME, NULL, NULL, &ret_size);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true; goto errored;
        }
        c_name.resize(ret_size);
        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_NAME, c_name.size(), c_name.data(), &ret_size);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true; goto errored;
        }
        name = std::string(c_name.begin(), c_name.end());
        name = std::regex_replace(name, std::regex("[' ']{2,}"), " ");

        cl_device_type   devType;
        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, sizeof(cl_device_type), (void *)&devType, NULL);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true; goto errored;
        }



        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&compute_units, NULL);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true; goto errored;
        }
        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), (void *)&max_work_size, NULL);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true; goto errored;
        }
        CWorker::eWorkerType type;
        if (devType & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)
            type = CWorker::eWorkerType::GPU;
        else
            if (devType & CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)
                type = CWorker::eWorkerType::CPU;


        if (type == CWorker::eWorkerType::CPU)
        {
            if (compute_units > 8)
                max_work_size = compute_units / 4;
            else if (compute_units == 8)
                max_work_size = 2;
            else
                max_work_size = 1;

        }
        ret = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[y], CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), (void *)&max_alloc, NULL);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            error = true;
            goto errored;
        }
    errored:
        if (error != true)
        {
            CWorker  * w = new CWorker();

            w->setDevice(devices[y]);
            w->setMaxComputeUnits(compute_units);
            w->setMaxMemAlloc(max_alloc);
            w->setMaxWorkGroupSize(max_work_size);
            w->setName(name);
            std::cmatch cm;
            if (std::regex_search(name.data(), cm, std::regex("\\w\+")))
                w->setShortName(std::string(cm[0]) +"-"+ std::to_string(mWorkers.size()+1));
            w->setContext(context);
            w->setType(type);

            mWorkers.push_back(w);
        }
    }

    nrOfActiveContexts++;
}

if (mWorkers.size() > 0)
    mInitialised = true;
if (mWorkers.size() > 0)
    return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: the kernels though very complicated are pure C.

Comment: by the way I'm quite paranoid to solve this so.. every worker executes multiple of kernels and I put clFinish after each call to be sure where it failed. the nvidia GPU fails on the first one:)

Comment: huseyin tugrul buyukisik; I might have overstated the complication of the kernels. They are complected in that they perform cryptographic functions which in the sense of programmatic complexity are not that much complicated. the kernels share a single large memory buffer. each hasing function constitutes a single kernel these are synchronized with   barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)

Comment: on a server with two platforms (each platform with a single CPU) everything works fine

Comment: NVidia alone works top-notch

Comment: huseyin? what do you mean by cloning the nvidia object? I would surely like to try this out on a dual GPU setup no access to such right now. any way to mimic this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180074/discussion-between-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik-and-vega4).

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely the problem is with how the context is being created:

> context = clCreateContext(***NULL***, numberOfDevices, devices.data(), NULL, NULL, &ret);

The first parameter being passed is `NULL` which according to the [OpenCL manual](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html) means that the platform being selected is implementation defined:

> Specifies a list of context property names and their corresponding values. Each property name is immediately followed by the corresponding desired value. The list is terminated with 0. properties can be NULL in which case the platform that is selected is implementation-defined.

Try passing something like this:

```
cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[i])(), 0};
context = clCreateContext(properties, numberOfDevices, devices.data(), NULL, NULL, &ret);
```

If that doesn't help then maybe try to initialize Nvidia first (if that is not the case already). It may be that Intel is initialized first and it's OpenCL version driver is newer than Nvidia (for example Intel OpenCL 2.0 vs Nvidia 1.2) and some of that is being used for Nvidia hence error.